# Get the index of an object I just added to an ArrayList in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, indexing

I want to load a series of objects to an ArrayList, and return the index of where it was added so it can be used later directly from the ArrayList. It'd be akin to me loading a set of 5 frames for a graphic and calling the data for frame 3 directly from the list.
Upon looking around at a couple potential posts that may be related, I found something that was related, and made me wonder. Is there even a built in function to GET the index of a recently added object?

The link I am looking at that made me think of this was: [ArrayList indexOf() returns wrong index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113696/arraylist-indexof-returns-wrong-index)

Basically, the way I was looking at it was that I would do something along the lines of the following psuedocode:

```
    private ArrayList<FrameData> mylistofframeshere = new ArrayList();
    FrameData Framenumberone = new FrameData(constructorblah goes in here);
    int wherediditgo = mylistofframeshere.add(Framenumberone);
```

Or I thought I could do something along the lines of

```
    mylistofframeshere.getindex(Framenumberone);
```

My backgrounds in coding are more procedural based at this point, so I am more used to knowing what the index is, just in order to place the data to begin with. I looked around at the oracle documentation as well, with findings something similar to the above link. Any suggestions??

**EDIT :** I'm going to add some extra clarification in here, because I really didn't put enough effort into the example and explanation.

Another example of trying to use something like a direct index of a list would be if I had a set of tiles I wanted to use as terrain for a game or something. I would load a set of possible tiles for the area into a central ArrayList. Upon trying to place these tiles, I would just reference the pre-loaded object I have in my ArrayList in order to draw the appropriate bitmap/whatever.

I'm still a bit new to Java, so I'm willing to bet it's just something simple I'm overlooking in the mechanics of using these datatypes. I'll keep editing this until I get the explanation right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add something to an `ArrayList`, it goes to the last available space. In other words:

```
List<FrameData> list = new ArrayList<FrameData>();
list.add(frame1);

FrameData frame = list.get(list.size() - 1); //frame == frame1
```

But I wonder why you would need to do that. If you explain more about what you are trying to achieve, there might be a different / better way to get to the same result.

Comment: For starts, that helps a lot. So there really is no direct return or way to get the index or direct reference of an object that is loaded to an array. Perhaps I misunderstand the proper usage of these things.

Secondly, in response to your answer, I also edited the main post a bit to clarify things a bit. Hopefully it will make more sense now. Thank you for the information thus far!

Comment: Have you considered using a hashmap? You could do something like `map.put("black tile", blackTile);` and later on `tile = map.get("black tile");` to get that tile back.

Comment: Would this work if multiple worker threads are trying to simply access the data to produce their own bitmap?

Upon reading the google docs on the subject, it seems that this would be the way to go.

Comment: In a multi threaded context you can use a ConcurrentHashMap which is a thread-safe hashmap.

Comment: Oh wow, so I'd use the ConcurrentHashMap to load all my objects into the table with set labels, and then use something like an ArrayList to make a list of objects that actually use those resources from the hashmap. Makes sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There is a method like `ArrayList.indexOf(object);` , Try using that method to get index of the object

Comment: This only returns the first found instance of the object. I need to find a specific instance of that type of object. Say for example I've got a list of monsters of all of the same type on the screen, how would I pick out a specific monster? Say I wanted to have that monster be invulnerable until the others are dead, I need to know which monster that is in the list so I can set it's properties correctly at load and after my conditions are met.

Comment: Something like that should be a property on the Monster object and should have nothing to do with the list itself. So to achieve this, you would add a property, say `private boolean invincible` to the Monster class. Then in its overridden equals method, you should check this condition. When you do this, `ArrayList.indexOf(object)` will return the right instance of Monster you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to use the index for. If you simply need to map each element in your list to a key so you can later retrieve the element with the key, you should perhaps consider using a HashMap. If you are more concerned with the ordering, you can use a List. As someone already answered, the index with be incremented as you add elements into the list. If you know the total number of frames you will have before hand, you can initialize an ArrayList by passing in the size as an argument to its constructor, then add each frame by manually specifying the index with list.add(0...size-1, element).

In short,

1. If you simply want to store and retrieve by your own key /
   incremented key -> use a HashMap.
2. If ordering is important, use a list.

Comment: If anything I'd be using a particular setting or object to be duplicated FROM the ArrayList I'd be using. The idea is to load a set of resources into the list and reference directly to the list as to where to place everything on a bitmap/whatever.

Comment: From what you say, it sounds like you might just be better off with a good old 2 (or perhaps 3) dimensional array of your object type. Then you can create other similar arrays for storing other properties. For example, imagine a 4x4 array of some object, and instances at (2,3) and (0,2) have some special properties such as invincibility. You could just create another 4x4 boolean array, and mark these elements as true, while the rest could be false. By traversing this array, you could figure out which objects (at the same set of points) have this property in the other array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ArrayList` in this way, you can use a `Map<Integer,FrameData>`. you can replace `Integer` with anything which might fit better in your project.